# Import .ipynb notebook without running it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have 2 **.ipynb** notebooks, A & B. I want to use some funcionts/class of A in B. **Without running A**.

Notebook "A":

```py
class class_i_want_to_import_to_use:
    def __init__(self, x):
        print (x)
        
print ("Main that i don't want to run when importing ")
```

Notebook B

```py
import import_ipynb
import A
b=A.class_i_want_to_import_to_use("run it in B notebook")
```

Out:

```py
importing Jupyter notebook from A.ipynb
Main that i don't want to run when importing  #DONT WANT TO SEE THIS
run it in B notebook
```

is this possible or do i need to separate all my functions intoa  notebook that doesn't run anything  ?

Comment: Importing a file will always execute it as well - that's what makes the class definitions visible in the first place. It's up to you to ensure there are no undesirable side-effects when importing your file. Look into `__name__ == "__main__"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `__name__ == 'main'` trick.

Check here for more info [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

```
class class_i_want_to_import_to_use:
    def __init__(self, x):
        print (x)

#this block will not be executed by import
#but it will get executed when running the script
if __name__ == 'main':       
    print ("Main that i don't want to run when importing ")
```

Comment: Great, can I use __name__=="main": over multiple cell blocks? I dont want to lose readablility by putting all "main" into one notebook cell

Comment: You can add `if __name__ == 'main':` to each cell, if you need. The common practice is, however, to put all in one block at the end of the script. I suggest you to use the notebook to sketch your ideas, but then write a proper python file if you want to use it as a package.